# array - out of bounds with random number

Tags: java

I have the following class called `Clinica`

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Clinica {
    //atributos
    private int[][] calendariosEnf;
    private int[][] calendariosMed;

    //Constructor
    public Clinica(){
        calendariosEnf = new int[12][31];
        calendariosMed = new int[12][31];
    }

    //Sets y gets
    //Calendario para las enfermeras
    public void setCalendariosEnf(int[][] calendariosEnf){
        this.calendariosEnf = calendariosEnf;
    }
    public int[][] getCalendariosEnf(){
        return calendariosEnf;
    }

    //Calendario para los medicos
    public void setCalendariosMed(int[][] calendariosMed){
        this.calendariosMed = calendariosMed;
    }
    public int[][] getCalendariosMed(){
        return calendariosMed;
    }

    Listas lista1 = new Listas();
    public void agregarCalEnf(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int min = 1;
        int max = 5;
        for(int m = 0; m < 11; m++){
            for(int d = 0; d < 30; d++){
                int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                calendariosEnf[d][m] = randomNum;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

If I try to print one file, for example `calendariosEnf[1][4]`, I get the following message

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
```

Anyone can help me where I got the index wrong?

I created the class Prueba, to check if the program is working ...

```
public class Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Listas list = new Listas();
        Clinica clin = new Clinica();
        list.agregarMedicos();
        clin.agregarCalEnf();
        System.out.println(clin.getCalendariosEnf()[1][4]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your main method?

Answer (score 2):

```
      for(int m = 0; m < 11; m++){
            for(int d = 0; d < 30; d++){
                int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                calendariosEnf[d][m] = randomNum;
            }
        }
```

`d` cannot be larger than 11, otherwise out of bound.

And the `m` can from 0 to 11 (**inclusive**), and `d` can from 0 to 30 (**inclusive**).

```
    for(int m = 0; m < 12; m++){
            for(int d = 0; d < 31; d++){
                int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                calendariosEnf[m][d] = randomNum;
            }
        }
```